# React Navigation 6 - Custom header height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a custom header component:

```
function CustomHeader() {
    return (
       <View style={{ height: headerHeight }}>
          {/* Some buttons in a row... */}
          <View 
            style={{ 
              position: "absolute",
              alignSelf: "center",
              top: headerHeight/2
            }} 
          />
       </View>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I am absolutely positioning a view in the center of my header, with a top of headerHeight/2.

For getting headers height I am doing:

```
 import { useHeaderHeight } from "@react-navigation/elements";

 const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

But... it returns me 0, as in my stack navigator I am doing:

```
 screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
 }}
```

because, I am rendering the custom header inside the Screen.

How can I solve this problem? I need to get the default headers height used in Stack Navigators in order to stylize my component.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `useHeaderHeight` hook is for getting the height of a header that's rendered by React Navigation.

If you just want to get the default header height, then you need to use `getDefaultHeaderHeight`:

```js
import { getDefaultHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
import { useSafeAreaFrame, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

// ...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const frame = useSafeAreaFrame();
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const headerHeight = getDefaultHeaderHeight(frame, false, insets.top);

  // ...

}
```

Comment: How would you do the same in class components?